# What does $\text{dom}(\Gamma)$ mean in the context of an inference rule?

Tags: type-theory, term-rewriting

In the wikipedia page on [pure type systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_type_system), it gives the following inference rule:

> $\frac{\Gamma \vdash A : s \quad x \notin \text{dom}(\Gamma)}{\Gamma, x : A \vdash x : A }\quad \text{(start)}$

What does $\text{dom}(\Gamma)$ mean here? These are string rewriting systems, so $\Gamma$ is supposed to be a string of symbols, a purely syntactic object. I'm not sure what a "domain of a string" is.

Comment: $\Gamma$ here is interpreted as a function from a set of variable names to the set of types. $x \notin \mathrm{dom}(\Gamma)$ means that $x$ is a fresh variable name, not in context.

Comment: @varkor, thank you. Just to check that I understand what you're saying: I was thinking of it as a string of typing statements $t_1:T_1,...,t_n:T_n$, where $t_i$ is a term variable and $T_i$ a specific type (not a type variable). Instead, you're saying, interpret this as a function $\Gamma$ defined by $\Gamma(t_i)=T_i$ for all $i\in \{1,...,n\}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right. (You might see other ways of defining contexts in other sources, e.g. as lists of types.)

Comment: @varkor, Thanks. If you set this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to define contexts in type theories. In this style, we assume there is some infinite set of variable names $V$ and define the context $\Gamma : V \rightharpoonup S$ as a partial function from the set of variable names to the set of types. $\mathrm{dom}(\Gamma)$ is then the subset of $V$ on which $\Gamma$ is defined, i.e. the variables in the context $\Gamma$. To require that $x \notin \mathrm{dom}(\Gamma)$ is asking for $x$ to be a fresh variable for the context $\Gamma$.